# making the uipagecontrol animation look like uinavigationcontrol animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm using the concept of the ui page control.

For example, I have multiple similar views.  Let say 10 news articles.  I put them in a a page control and am able to swipe between them.

However, I want to mimic the animation that the UINavController does.  Is this possible?  ie: not have the pages scroll end to end but instead a slight overlap and effect where one panel slides out at twice the speed of the one below it sliding in.

Any Ideas?

Comment: UIPageControl does not have any animations or transitions associated with it. What are you actually using to do your animations?

Comment: Are you actually using a UIPageViewController? I guess you mistook it for the UIPageControl which is not any kind of container.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not getting wrong understanding of your question..
As this is not possible to do with existing page controls you need your own logic
This is how it should be handled, you will need to adjustments as per your requirement..

**Rough logic**

```
[self.view addSubview:nextArticleView];
nextArticleView.frame = // set offscreen frame, in the direction you want it to appear from
```

//Set more time as newArticle should overlap to existing articles view

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 
      animations:^{
                nextArticleView.frame = // desired end location (current articles initial frame)
                  }];
```

//set less time as current article should slide fast

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 
      animations:^{
                self.view.frame = // desired end location (off screen)
                  }];
```